# LineageOS Linux Kernel version

Tags: lineageos

I use LineageOS 14.1 on i9305 and have been pondering updating to 15.1 since it's decently mature now.

Recently I was looking into the Linux Kernel versions that Android uses.
Refer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history

The questions I have are:

1) My ROM on my S3 shows Kernel version 3.0.101-lineage-gb7ffe7f. So is this actually Linux Kernal v3? Now shouldn't Android N run on Kernel 4.4.1 or is an older kernel version just expected on older phones for compatibility.

Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: The AOSP version of Android N runs on Linux 4.4, but that doesn't necessarily mean any derivated ROMs must also run on that kernel.

Comment: Device maintainer may port over new kernel for old devices, but AFAIK often the kernel version stays around what the manufacturer uses on their stock ROMs so as to avoid that hard work.

Comment: For you as user it doesn't really matter if ROM is functional just use it